# Please explain this line of javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
jBox.prototype.position = function (options)
{
  // this line
  !options && (options = {});

}
```

In conventional programming boolean statements are used in if else statements.
What does  !options && (options = {}); translate too?

options is a json or array. What does !options mean?

options = {} is assigning a  empty json to variable options, how does it return a boolean value to be used  with &&.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: You might want to look up each individual thing you don't understand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is a good place to start

Comment: "how does it return a boolean value to be used with &&" — `&&` doesn't operate on boolean values

Comment: I somehow find `options = options || {}` to be more readable.

Comment: Careful with the terminology. `{}` is not a "json", it's an object literal.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen — I'd just use a default argument value these days.

Comment: @Quentin: in javascript, does the default argument value protect from a falsey value being explicitly passed? `position('')`. Subtle difference, but matters sometimes.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah sure, but not possible in all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
!options && (options = {});
```

is the equivalent of:

```
if(!options) { 
    options = {}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that if `options` is a falsy value (empty) then initialize it with an empty object literal.